# In Excel can a listbox have a drop down instead of the scroll bar?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am replacing some of the combo boxes in my spreadsheet for list boxes so users can select more than one item. the problem that I am running into is that i have a long list of items and I don't have the space to make the listbox show multiple lines. It would best if I can make the listbox look and act like a combobox with that ability to select more than one item. I can't seem to find the property to make the list box have a dropdown menu.

The middle control in the picture is the listbox and you can see the scroll bar. Scrolling through 30 items like that isn't practical. Is there a property to give it a pull down menu like combo boxes?

[image]

thanks.

Comment: Not that I have ever seen.  You could write code to make a taller listbox appear below the listbox being clicked. Make it appear on click but not sure when you would want it to go away. Or you could just resize it on click.

Comment: Do you really not have the space? Does your form already have a scrollbar that you are fully using? (Meaning it is taller than the user's screen)

Comment: tell me...item beside **"All"** is a check box or not? can you post your code?

Comment: @Nicolas The check box next to **"ALL"** is a property of a listbox set ListStyle to 1 - fmListStyleOption to enable the check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I decided the best way for me would be to add an item in the combobox called 'multiple' that when selected opens a userform with a listbox that lets the user select multiple items. I put all the selected items into an array and then pass them back to the worksheet. It's not as straight forward as I wanted but it keeps the worksheet clean. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible so this isn't a direct answer, but the next best thing you could have is a locked textbox next to a combo. If you want to show the results of their choice, a user can click on something in the combo and the textboxwould write it like this:

```
optionA
```

If the user selects a second one from the combo, the textbox appends the second one:

```
optionA; optionB
```

Sort of like e-mail recipients.

Have a small button next to that so the users can clear the textbox if they make a mistake.

I can help with the code if needed.